# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm currently debugging our specFlow test and this is pretty new to me. I've tried just about all of the suggestions I found online, with no luck.I'll post below how Newtonsoft.Json is being used.

```
  [When(@"I run for Sku='(.*)' OptionId1='(.*)' OptionId2='(.*)' OptionId3='(.*)'")]
   public async Task WhenIRunForSku(string Sku, int? OptionId1, int? OptionId2, int? OptionId3)
    {  
       var request = new ProcessCartonBySkuRequest()
                {
                    SkuOptionSets = new List<SkuOptionSet>()
                    {
                        new SkuOptionSet
                        {
                            Sku = Sku,
                            Option1Id = OptionId1,
                            Option2Id = OptionId2,
                            Option3Id = OptionId3
                        }
                    },
                    CallerContext = new CallerContext
                    {
                        ApplicationName = "IntegrationTest",
                        MethodName = nameof(WhenIRunForSku)
                    }
                };
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await TestHost.Client.PostAsync("uri here", content);
                var success = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();

      Assert.True(success);
    }
```

Content is coming back as null, and thats when the error is thrown.

```
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int? Option1Id { get; set; }
    public int? Option2Id { get; set; }
    public int? Option3Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionString => BuildOptionString();
```

Full error:[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu7wf.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkDwx.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you are expecting a bare bool from the server (so either `true` or `false` directly in the response), but I'm guessing the server is actually returning a JSON object (JSON objects begin with `{`.)

Comment: the response I'm getting back is "null" because of the json parsing error. So the content that should be be getting sent through post async is null. @BrianRogers

Comment: Right, because a JSON object can't be parsed to a bool.  Try changing `var success = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();` to `var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and then dump out `responseString` to the debug window.  See what you get.

Comment: thanks Brian I appreciate you helping and hmm I tried that but its still coming back as "null"  I'll add a picture above of the debugger @BrianRogers

Comment: Can you paste the full exception details and stack trace?

Comment: @N.Dogac I'll post a picture above of the full test output window,thanks

Comment: @Louis please post errors and code as text. That way they are easy to read, easy to copy, and can be indexed by search engines so others having the same problem can also find your question.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi ah ok, I'll do that now --thanks

Comment: Which specific line in your code throws the exception?